Why bar chart starts on the x axis leaving a gap in the first unit

BarChart[StringLength[StringSplit["A long time ago, in a galaxy far,far away", ","]]] 

While I can follow the reason for three bars as there are 2 commas in the string, unable to grasp the reason why first unit in the x axis left empty (or with zero value).

You may specify the origin of the axes by "AxesOrigin". E.g.:
BarChart[{StringLength[
   StringSplit["A long time ago, in a galaxy far,far away", ","]]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1.35, 0}]



So by default the first unit on x axis starts with a space and not from the origin?

BarChart[{StringLength[StringSplit["A long time ago, in a galaxy far,far away", ","]]}, AxesOrigin->{1.35,0}]   For this code, curly brace before StringLength seems optional and even without curly brace which perhaps denoting that it will have list elements will give the same output. BarChart[StringLength[StringSplit["A long time ago, in a galaxy far,far away", ","]], AxesOrigin->{1.35,0}]   This is because StringLength has Listable attribute?

Yes, by default it starts with a space. And yes, the curly bracket is only necessary if you have more than one set of data to plot. In your example it is superfluous.

Using BarSpacing:
ab = StringLength[
  StringSplit["A long time ago, in a galaxy far,far away", ","]];
BarChart[{ab}
 , BarSpacing -> {Small, 1}
 ]




Now try the following and change the inter-group spacing.
de = {4, 8, 12, 16};
BarChart[{ab, de}
 , BarSpacing -> {Small, 1}
 ]


Try it with a few Null entries and only one group. I can't seem to find this explained in the docs, although perhaps the explanation is there.
ef = {15, 16, 8, ,};
BarChart[ef]


I will definitely go through it though it looks a bit advanced.
